# Azure App Service Authentication - 302 when trying to GET /.auth/me

Tags: reactjs, oauth, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I have a reactjs web app which is hosted on Azure App Services, using App Service Authentication.

My app authenticates properly and from inside the app I'm attempting to GET /.auth/me so that I can read the access tokens to use for some future API requests but am receiving a 302 in response. The response redirects to login.microsoft.com even though the first request (to load the app) has already been authenticated.

```
const headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'credentials': 'include'
};

return (dispatch) => {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers,
    };

    return fetch("/.auth/me", requestOptions) 
        .then(parseResponseAndHandleErrors)
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error)
        });
}
```

I think I must be missing a cookie or a header in the GET but the docs don't give much information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#retrieve-tokens-in-app-code

> From your client code (such as a mobile app or in-browser JavaScript), send an HTTP GET request to /.auth/me. The returned JSON has the provider-specific tokens.

I have tried setting `'credentials': 'same-origin'` but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: have you tried credentials:'same-origin'?

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier we've tried that as well. I should have included that in the question.

Comment: i remember something like setting allow all requests but validate or something like that in the azure management portal long time ago. dont know if this is related.

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier I figured it out. The credentials option was the key, but it was in the wrong place.  See my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure this out after looking in to more detail at the 'credentials' option of the `fetch()` API.

`'credentials' : 'same-origin'` should not be included in the headers, but rather as a seperate request option:

```
const headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

return (dispatch) => {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers,
        'credentials': 'same-origin'  //credentials go here!!!
    };

    return fetch("/.auth/me", requestOptions) 
        ......
}
```